# Configure routes to access WAN and LAN through diffrent interfaces

Tags: networking, routing, xubuntu, lan

In my organization. Some useful technical websites are blocked by the firewall.
In my machine i got three interfaces **eth0, wlan0, wwlan0**

```
eth0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 00:9c:02:93:b1:b4  
          inet addr:10.0.69.63  Bcast:10.0.71.255  Mask:255.255.252.0
        ...
          RX bytes:551526655 (551.5 MB)  TX bytes:71851444 (71.8 MB)
          Interrupt:20 Memory:d4700000-d4720000 

wlan0     Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr ac:81:12:d2:57:d4  
          inet addr:192.168.1.13  Bcast:192.168.1.255 Mask:255.255.255.0
        ...

wwan0     Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 32:ab:e4:44:7c:3d  
          inet addr:105.152.231.158  Bcast:105.152.231.159  Mask:255.255.255.252
        ...
          RX bytes:288643752 (288.6 MB)  TX bytes:28286606 (28.2 MB)
```

When I disable eth0 i can access the WAN through wwan0 but of course i loose access to the organization LAN.

How can i configure my routing table to :

**1.** Access all LAN destinations (10. * . * . *) through **eth0**
**2.** Access all WAN destinations through **wwlan0**
**3.** Access all WAN destinations through **eth0** when **wwlan0** is disabled
**4.** disable **1.** ,  **2.** and  **3.** rules whenever i activate **wlan0**